# What is the difference between ホワイトシャツ・ワイシャツ and 背広?

Tags: vocabulary, nuances

How do we decide whether to call a shirt a ワイシャツ or 背広 ? What's the difference in nuance between the two terms?

Side question: [EDICT](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E3%83%9B%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%84)
claims that a ホワイトシャツ is a white business shirt but even if it's a gray or black (or what-have-you) colored business shirt, we can still call it a ホワイトシャツ or ワイシャツ right?

Comment: These terms are not synonymous, as any dictionary would tell you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're confused here. 背広 is a suit, not a shirt. As to the second question, ワイシャツ is the generic name for a dress shirt, button-down shirt, oxford shirt, etc. Color doesn't enter into it. Also, ホワイトシャツ is archaic now.

Comment: @@rdb ok thx =D